# To be minus of a sum of money periodically?

Tags: phrase-request

I'm looking for a short urban idiom that I seems to knew but it eludes my mind.
Let's say somebody spends a thousand dollars on something periodically. How do I casually describe that he is minus of a thousand dollars each time?
Can I say "He is down on a grand every time he ..."?

Comment: You could also say "He [drops](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/drop) a grand on new clothes at the beginning of every semester." where "drop" is slang for spending money. It doesn't have to be periodically though.

Comment: It is also fine to use **down**, but we don't say "down *on* a grand", just "he is down a grand every time he..."

Answer (score 2):

A phrase that might work is **to be *out* the money**, which means to be poorer by that amount, or have lost that amount.

For example,

> [All you have to do is refuse to turn that steel over to me. and I'm out a million dollars a day.](https://books.google.com/books?id=2F2RJ95Esy8C&q=%22I%27m%20out%20a%22%20dollars&dq=%22I%27m%20out%20a%22%20dollars&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQw7uF_OzvAhU9GVkFHQnVAZcQ6AEwAnoECAIQAg)

> [Dropping a regular cheap bulb package means that I'm out a dollar or less.  But if I drop a fluorescent, I'm out four or five dollars.](https://books.google.com/books?id=8HG1AAAAIAAJ&q=%22I%27m%20out%20a%22%20dollars&dq=%22I%27m%20out%20a%22%20dollars&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQw7uF_OzvAhU9GVkFHQnVAZcQ6AEwBXoECAYQAg)

> [I'm out the money for the new water heater, the window blinds, and the carpet...](https://books.google.com/books?id=ydVNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&dq=%22I%27m%20out%20the%22%20money&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJurzi_OzvAhVAMVkFHYgNDmkQ6AEwBHoECAMQAg)